# Are moderator positions granted for life?

Tags: discussion, moderators, recent-activity

I was looking at a [list of our amazing moderators](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and came across [Jesse Dorsey](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/14/jesse-dorsey), who has been inactive for over 5 years.  Is there any sort of criteria to retain your moderatorship?

Comment: The mod in question [voted to close a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/172029/i-have-an-editable-swf-with-refferal-protection-how-would-i-remove-that) on May 20, 2019. Your question is still reasonable to ask, but your statement regarding that mod's inactivity is incorrect. [Full list of SE activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/45404/noctrine?tab=activity).

Comment: Related SO meta post [How is moderator inactivity identified and handled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256735).

Comment: And [Can a moderator resign the post or be dismissed, and why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259315/can-a-moderator-resign-the-post-or-be-dismissed-and-why/259317#259317).

Comment: If you want to file a complaint about the moderation of the site (or the lack of moderation, or moderators?), I think your best bet is to [contact](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/contact) the staff directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> list of our amazing moderators

Thanks for the compliment :)

---

> Are moderator positions granted for life?

As long as they're active and/or willing to moderate the site and/or don't do naughty things, yes, we can consider that they'll be moderators for life.

There are a couple of ways to view "activity":

- Posting questions and answers (doing this is not part of the responsibilities of a mod)
- Commenting, [reviewing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review), editing posts, etc. (we have a user that only flags no longer needed comments)
- Performing mod-only activity: handling flags, suspending users (not that we do that often), etc.

Thus, a mod could be super silent and look inactive but spend their days deleting no-longer-needed "thanks" comments.

> Is there any sort of criteria to retain your moderatorship?

That's up to the mod and to StackExchange CM staff. A mod can decide to step down. The decision could also come from the CMs, or from the mod and CMs.

As an example, [Tetrad](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/51/tetrad) was a mod before, but he no longer has his <strike>hammer</strike> diamond.

Comment: I want a hammer. I'll run again if we elect more.